# Youtube Api : Error 400 Bad Request while uploading videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

I'm getting an error code 400 Bad Request while uploading some videos.

Title limit is 100 characters,description limit is 5000 characters, tag limit is 500 characters.

Youtube Data Api v2.0

My code is;

http://pastebin.com/qpNvZ4Sy

And i'm getting this response ;

http://pastebin.com/0MYqftLv

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: off the top of my head, it's a bit hard to figure out given the two pastebin's you've provided.

In the first case, I need you to tell me what library your using to interface with you-tube, as the code you've given is not "generic" code, that is it's using a larger toolkit or framework, in the second case the response you got back is not a response from YT, it looks like part of a stack trace from .NET itself, to that point since the stack trace seems to be incomplete, then I need you to provide the full stack trace if you can.

Comment: finally.. the "400" response code, now that **IS** an actual response code coming back from YT, and whats more it is exactly what it says **bad request**, that is it's likely that YT didn't like the data you provided, or you provided a GET when it should have been a POST, if you have any more data available, EG: a fiddler trace please provide that also.

Comment: Thank you @shawty . I just found that i get this error because of UTF-8 characters. I used this code http://pastebin.com/ZMHWUCwR
to encode this characters but it turns "??????????" on Youtube.
I upload my videos with Resumable Uploads and according to this link
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/fNyR_P-5eDg Jeffrey Posnick,from Youtube Api Team, said "Resumable Uploads server-side code is mishandling to encode UTF-8 and it will be fixed on mid-month of August 2010. I think that they already solved this problem on server side..
Is there any solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: There are no issues with support for UTF-8 encoded strings and uploads at this time. If the strings you provide are turning into "???" characters when displayed on YouTube, then you're not encoding them as UTF-8 before sending them, or you're specifying a non-UTF-8 content encoding in your HTTP request. I recommend you move to v3 of the API and try out https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

Comment: @JeffPosnick Sir, these samples that you gave me on that link didn't work for what i'm trying to do because i couldn't find these dll's using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2; using Google.Apis.Authentication; using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2; using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth; using Google.Apis.Samples.Helper; using Google.Apis.Services; using Google.Apis.Util; using Google.Apis.Youtube.v3; using Google.Apis.Youtube.v3.Data; on Nuget.org Can you please please give me a link to find these dlls for C#? Thank you –

Comment: Are japanese and russian alphabets UTF-8 or non-UTF-8 ?

Comment: There are UTF-8 representations of any Unicode character. You just need to make sure your strings are properly constructed in your language of choice. The .NET client library was recently updated; published examples work with https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=contrib#hg%2F1.5.0-beta%253Fstate%253Dclosed and we're working on getting them updated to the new OAuth 2 libraries.

Comment: Thank you @JeffPosnick . How can i upload videos to Youtube using V3 with api key on C#? If you have any documents or examples for that,can you please provide me? I've been searching that since yesterday but i couldn't find..

Comment: v3 samples for .NET are not proper..We cannot use it.Can you please provide us a proper sample? Also we are still having 400 Bad Request Error on V2. I read an article on this webpage http://markmail.org/message/sbvvjtcl6sruejrs#query:+page:1+mid:elvy6qloh2q3z3a3+state:results which is answered by you. This 400 Bad Request Error might be a server-side error or a security thing. When i change the name of the video, i can upload it very easily but when i write the original name of the video, i cannot upload it.

Comment: We're in the process of updating the v3 samples for .NET to use the newer 1.7.0 library classes. In the meantime, before it's official, here's a preview: http://pastebin.com/vLYeTVmn

Comment: Thank you very much @JeffPosnick. I will be waiting for the official update. I am so happy right now. Finally,i can solve my problems.