# Visual Basic Access Token Youtube API Returning Error 400

Tags: vb.net, youtube-api

So, I'm trying to make a program that will upload videos for me so I don't have to take so much time, and I've come up with the following code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim bytearray As String = "code=4/5tC9qk5APvWf_05GJRG-Ws5Ph4B1xXMZd0gw4iZEB50&
client_id=349673303318-cp0upvjfcijukhnloppnpl5v57qkrr53.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=s7gStNsZWua50Hlpot2XfSga&
redirect_uri=https://localhost/oauth2callback&
grant_type=authorization_code"
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.ContentLength = bytearray.Length
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write((Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bytearray)), 0, bytearray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(Convert.ToString(response.GetResponseStream))
        response.Close()
    End Sub

End Module
```

This is in Visual Basic.

The problem is that it returns an Error 400 (Bad Request) from the server when I send the request.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check additional error details then you may refer to [YouTube - Errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#errors) to help you troubleshoot encountered error.

Additionally, comments in this SO post - [Youtube Api : Error 400 Bad Request while uploading videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637590/youtube-api-error-400-bad-request-while-uploading-videos) might also help.